# C# Abstract methods, readonly properties

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, properties

I have an assignment (bunch of oop stuff, polymorphism and inheritance) and amongst other things I have to do the following:

1. **I need to add an abstract method to the class Vehicle** (called *calculateOccupancy()*) which has to return the % of the leftover space in a vehicle. I then have to implement that in my derived classes. The issue here is, I have 3 derived classes, two of them have 2 attributes and one has 3. So how do I make my abstract method, so that it can accept 2 or 3 arguments.
2. **I have to add a unchangeable property to the class Person**, and the property has to return the first letter of the name and surname, divided by a dot.

```
namespace Example
{
    abstract class Vehicle
    { 
        //class member variables, most likely unnecessary for the questions
        private Person driver;
        private string vehicleBrand;
        private string vehicleType;
        private double fuelConsumption;
        private double gasTankSize;
        private string fuelType;

        //the default constructor
        public Vehicle()
        {}

        //The abstract method from question 2
        // how to make it so that it wont error when I need to 
        //put in 3 variables instead of two, meaning, how would I add int c
        public abstract double calculateOccupancy (int a, int b);

        //The derived class that implements the method
        class Bus : Vehicle
        {
            private int allSeats; 
            private int allStandingSeats; 
            private int busPassengers; //the number of passengers

            //the constructor
            public Bus (int a, int b, int c)
            {
                allSeats=a;
                allStandingSeats=b;
                busPassengers=c;
            }

            //the abstract method 
            // needs to take in int b (standing seats)
            public override double calculateOccupancy(int a, int c)
            {
                 //this code calculates the leftover space in the vehicle
                 double busSpace=(busPassengers*100) / allSeats;
                 return busSpace;

                 //same code for the leftover standing space (int c)
            } 
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        protected string name;
        protected string lastName;
        //question 1
        //properties for char gender
        protected char gender;
        //question 3
        protected readonly string initials;

        //the code errors, at the get/set
        public char Gender
        {
            get{ return gender; }
            set {gender=value;}
        }

        /*and the property im not sure how to make
        public string Initials{}
        */
    }
```

I hope the comments add some clarity, rather than confusion, thank you for your help everybody.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: What do you mean? I wrote them in the description.

Comment: No, you posted requirements for the problem.  Are you expecting us to read the comments and figure out which of them are questions, and write code snippets to post?  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Please limit yourself to one question per post, and make it clear right up front what your question is.

Comment: @Simon #2 is probably ok, "So how do I make my abstract method, so that it can accept 2 or 3 arguments[?]" is a clear question statement. #1 and #3 are not so obvious. We see that you have a problem, but since there is no question attached to them, it looks like you just want us to solve the problem for you. We instead need to see a specific question that you have so that we can give you a specific answer. As Jeff said, you should limit a post to one question with only the code relevant to that question though.

Comment: I am a new user and my last question was down voted by some folks (it was pretty short and straightforward, not sure why the down votes) and that's why I am limited to this one post and cant post for 3 days. So I had to write up 3 questions in one post.  I understand that my question was somewhat poorly written and long, that's why I commented out the code. Thank you for your advice anyway @JeffLearman

Comment: @Sudsy1002 thank you for the advice

Comment: @Simon Is it an option to have `izracunajZasedenost()` use no parameters and use member variables that are declared on the deriving classes? Also, for #1 are they implying to replace its datatype of `char` with the newly created enum type?

Comment: Could I then still call the method izracunajZasedenost() on an object in Main()? like `Avtobus bus= new Avtobus (20,5,8); bus.izracunajZasedenost(20,5,8);`

Comment: @Simon - I highly recommend you translate the code to the English language.  Yes we can read requirements, but the code is almost non-sensical to an English speaker.  I see you have excellent written skills so why not?

Comment: What are the arguments you need to pass to `calculateOccupancy `? Seems to me the class already contains all the information you need; you could just read the values from `this.allSeats`, `this.busPassengers`, etc. That would solve the problem of whether to pass 2 or 3 arguments; pass 0 arguments instead.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey just did so, I dont know why I didnt do that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Give the "optional" values a value when you create the abstract method

```
public abstract double izracunajZasedenost (int a = -1, int b = -1) 
{
    if (a == -1){ 
        //do method with ignoring a
    }
};
```

Comment: You mean in the overrided method? @Marker

Comment: In both abstract and the overridden method.  Also if -1 is a valid value you can consider using a nullable int like so `public abstract double izracunajZasedenost (int a, int b, int? c=null)  {  if (c != null) ....`.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption going forward** - I threw some of your variable names into Google Translate and it seems to be Slovenian. I'm assuming that going forward which helped me make some clarity of what your code does.

1) **Replace** - If you already have a variable that is a `char` representing `spol` then I believe you're supposed to use the new `enum` type you are to create to represent it.

```
public enum Spol
{
    Moski = 0,
    Zenska = 1
}
```

Change:

```
protected char spol;
public char Spol
{
    get{ return spol; }
    set {spol=value;}
}
```

To: `public Spol Spol { get; set; }`

2) **Defaults & Conditions** - Use `int c = 0` as your 3rd parameter and use a formula/algorithm that ignores it if it is the default value.

3) **Getters** - This property doesn't have a setter and therefore cannot be changed (directly).

```
public string GiveThisAName
{
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ime))
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(priimek))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return ime[0] + '.' + priimek[0];
    }
}
```

**Notes**

1) Heavily recommend making the parameters of your capacity function (i.e. `izracunajZasedenost(int a, int b)`) to be named something useful (i.e. a name descriptive of what they do) other than `a` and `b`.

2) For the record, #1 seems more like an appropriate question for your instructor, teacher, or whoever gave you this assignment.

Comment: thank you, I translated it to english, should've done it at the start. 2. What do you mean as for #1 seems to be appropriate for the instructor. 3. Yeah it's was a dumb way of writing it up. I should have written it all in english. Again thank you for youre help!

Comment: #1 sounds less like a question for us and more like a question for your instructor because it sounds like you're unclear what the instructions say. I took a guess as to what they mean but there's no guarantee I am correct. Because obviously as you figured out, you cannot have two class members with the same name.